# Feature Flags - Should they be exposed to client applications?

Tags: flags, feature-selection

I'm considering using Feature Flags in a web based app that has both javascript/html and mobile native clients, and am trying to make an informed decision on the following:

### Should feature flags be exposed to client applications?

When discussing this with others, 2 approaches have appeared with how clients deal with feature flags, those being:

#### 1) Clients know nothing about feature flags at all.

Server side endpoints that respond with data would include extra data to say if a feature was on or off.

e.g. for a fictional endpoint, `/posts`, data could be returned like so

**enhanced ui feature enabled:**

```
{
  enhanced_ui: true,
  [1,2,3,4,5]
}
```

**enhanced ui feature disabled:**

```
{
  enhanced_ui: false,
  [1,2,3,4,5]
}
```

#### 2) Clients can access an endpoint, and ask for feature flag states.

e.g. `/flagstates`

```
{
  'enhanced_ui:true
}
```

Clients then use this to hide or show features as required.

#### Some thoughts:

Approach #1 has less moving parts - no client side libraries are needed for implementing gates at all.

The question comes up though - when dynamic flags are updated, how do clients know? We can implement pub/sub to receive notifications and reload clients, then they'd automatically get the new up to date data.

Approach #2 feels like it might be easier to manage listening for flag updates, since it's a single endpoint that returns features, and state changes could be pushed out easily.

Comment: On the dynamic flags point - why would you bother with notification approach, waiting for content reload sounds reasonable to me.

Comment: The app is a single page app, so no reloads like that occur

Comment: My point still stands though, feature switch does not sound like something that the app should react to immediately, so waiting for reload in spa sounds reasonable as well. This is my opinion though so please feel free to disagree.

Comment: agreed - _the world don't move to the beat of just one drum_

Comment: I would suggest you to take a look at aspnet zero and how they implemented features/editions. It has really good principles in my opinion and template for solution. Might be exactly what you are looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is something that interested me as well as I have a requirement to implement feature flags/switches in the product I am working on. I have been researching this area for the past week and I will share my findings and thoughts (I am not claiming they are best practice in any way). These findings and thoughts will be heavily based on [ASP.Net Zero](https://aspnetzero.com/) and [ASP.Net Boilerplate](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/?ref=az) as I found these to be the closest match for an example implementation for what I am looking for.

> Should feature flags be exposed to client applications?

Yes and no. If you are building a software as a service product (with multitenancy potentially), then you will most likely have to have some sort of management ui where admin users can manage (CRUD/Enable/Disable) features . This means that if you are building a SPA, you will obviously have to implement endpoints in your api (appropriately secured, of course) that your front end can use to retrieve details about the features and their current state for editing purposes. This could look like something below:

```
"features": [
    {
      "parentName": "string",
      "name": "string",
      "displayName": "string",
      "description": "string",
      "defaultValue": "string",
      "inputType": {
        "name": "string",
        "attributes": {
          "additionalProp1": {},
          "additionalProp2": {},
          "additionalProp3": {}
        }, 
      ....
```

Model for features can, of course, vary based on your problem domain, but above should give you an idea of a generic model to hold feature definition.

Now as you can see, there is more to the feature than just a boolean flag whether it is enabled or not - it may have attributes around it. This is something that was not obvious at all for me to begin with as I only thought about my problem in the context of fairly simple features (true/false) where as actually, there may be features that are a lot more complex.

Lastly, when your users will be browsing your app, if you are rendering the UI for tenant who has your *EnhancedUI* feature enabled, you will need to know if the feature is enabled. In ASP.Net Zero this done by using something called `IPermissionService`, which is implemented in both, front end and back end. In back end, the permission service would basically check if the user is supposed to be allowed to access some resource, which in feature switch context means to check whether the feature is enabled for a given tenant. In front end (Angular), the permission service retrieves these permissions (
`/api/services/app/Permission/GetAllPermissions`):

```
{
  "items": [
    {
      "level": 0,
      "parentName": "string",
      "name": "string",
      "displayName": "string",
      "description": "string",
      "isGrantedByDefault": true
    }
  ]
}
```

This can then be used to create some sort of `RouteGuard` where if something is not enabled or not allowed, you can appropriately redirect for example to an *Upgrade your edition* page.

Hopefully this gives you some ideas to think about.

Comment: thanks for the feedback! the whole idea of `config` and `context` about how a gate is evaluated, and how dynamic the evaluation is, is what seems to force the server into being the only thing that manages the calculated state of a gate at any time, otherwise you have the logic of gates in both the server and the client, and like all good SaaS, we can't trust the client, so we have to tell the client what it's allowed to do and not allowed to do. It can't make those decisions. It's this bit that seems to require the client be as dumb as possible.

Comment: Exactly, that’s why even if someone gets into your enhanced ui, it still needs permission to execute feature related backend functions.